# R Programming: Using a For Loop to create a mean for a given column across multiple files

Tags: r

I'm very much a beginner when it comes to R, so don't be surprised if there are some very obvious mistakes in my work below.

I have 332 csv files all formatted in the same way with the same column headers, and I'm trying to write a function that will give me the mean for a given column across a given set of those files. For instance, I want the mean for the column labeled "nitrate" for files 1:10, or just file 30, or all files 1:332.

Here's what I have so far:

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) 
    {
    setwd(directory)
    x <- c()    
    for (i in id) 
            {
        y <- read.csv(sprintf("%03d.csv", i))
        x <- append(x,y[pollutant],length(x))
            }
    setwd("D:/Documents/R Programming")
    lapply(x, mean, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
```

The problem is if I specify that I want to look at the mean for the "sulfate" column for files 1:5, this function will give me the means for the sulfate column for EACH of the those files, but what I'm looking for is the mean of all of the data in those 5 files.

Comment: I'm sure you'll find the answer here on SO if you search for "pollutantmean".

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I did notice that there are a lot of questions here related to this course. However, it seems everybody has a different approach to the problem and I don't want to just copy somebody else's work. I'd rather figure out a way to fix the function I'm trying to write, if it's salvageable at all.

Answer (score 1):

To anybody who may be interested, I got the code working.

```
pollutantmean <- function(directory, pollutant, id = 1:332) 
    {
    setwd(directory)
    x <- NULL   
    for (i in id) 
            {
        y <- read.csv(sprintf("%03d.csv", i))
        x <- c(x,y[[pollutant]])                }
    setwd("D:/Documents/R Programming")
    mean(x, na.rm = TRUE)
    }
```

I'm not sure why, but I believe the append function was throwing me off.